# Install program into folder which is equivalent to windows program files

Tags: 13.04, installed-programs

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I want to install NetBeans IDE, I feel like it shouldn't be installed into home directory, but don't know where is equivalent to windows program files folder, please explain me about where to install Ubuntu apps?

This is a screenshot I got from the internet, as default installation folder for NetBeans IDE

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real equivalent since [Linux is not Windows](http://linux.oneandoneis2.org/LNW.htm).

If you're installing netbeans for your own usage, it's reasonable to install it in your home directory, and the location it suggests is as good as any.

If you want to install it in a location where all users can get to it, there are several options.

Netbeans probably contains a lot of files and libraries, and on Unix systems these are usually installed in different locations (again, no direct equivalent to Program Files where you'd just dump every component for an application in its own directory; note that even on Windows this isn't strictly enforced as DLLs and other components can be scattered in several locations on the filesystem). For instance, binaries go in `/usr/bin` while libraries may go in `/usr/lib` and assorted data files somewhere in `/usr/share`.

About the closest thing you'll find to Program Files is the `/opt` directory, meant for " the installation of add-on application software packages." (see http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES). You can conceivably install in `/opt/netbeans` if you so choose.

have a read about the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to understand how a Linux filesystem is organized.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the directories unless under `/home` need root access to write.